# how to use android.hardware.camera2 on Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-camera2

I want to use android.hardware.camera2 inside **Fragment** and my app's MinSDK is 16 and it is not allowing to use android.hardware.camera2 package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in SDK 21. Also, you can follow this tutorial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html for more information.

Comment: can you share me a sample code to use camera2 on Fragment!